# Reading words from a file and putting into list

Tags: python, string, file, loops, python-3.x

Essentially, I have a huge file and all the file contains are multiple words per line, each separated by a space. Kind of like this:

```
WORD WORD WORD WORD
ANOTHER
WORD SCRABBLE BLAH
YES NO
```

What I want to do is put all the words in the file into one huge list, I tried using split but that didn't account for the new lines(\n)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading via `for line in f` splits on newline and it's efficient memory-wise (it reads one line at a time) but putting everything in a huge list is not. Anyway, if you insist:

```
huge_list = []

with open(huge_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        huge_list.extend(line.split())
```

To read the whole file into memory as a string, use `f.read()` instead:

```
huge_list = []

with open(huge_file, "r") as f:
    huge_list = f.read().split()
```

---

Input file (words separated by spaces and newlines):

```
WORD WORD WORD WORD
ANOTHER
WORD SCRABBLE BLAH
YES NO
```

Output of both examples:

```
>>> huge_list
['WORD', 'WORD', 'WORD', 'WORD', 'ANOTHER', 'WORD', 'SCRABBLE', 'BLAH', 'YES', 'NO']
>>>
```

Comment: I would like to put each word into the huge list as it's own element, not each line if possible for example it would be ['word','another', 'word', 'etc']

Comment: @user2918356 I'm not sure I understand. The two examples I posted will separate the lines and put each word into the 1-dimensional `huge_list`. Did you try running it?

Comment: @user2918356 `['word','another', 'word', 'etc']` is exactly what the output looks like.